# jQuery Large List Performance

Tags: jquery, json

I am having performance issues with a dynamically created, layered list with jquery. I retrieve my data via JSON from the server and then rendering it client side with this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    var subArr = myArray[i];
    var newElm = "<li id="+subArr.node_order+" value="+subArr.id+" class='list-item'><span>"+subArr.node_name+"</span><ul></ul></li>";
    var parent = $("li#"+subArr.parent_id+" ul");

    if(parent[0] != undefined){
        $(parent[0]).append(newElm);
    } else{
        sortable.html("<ul>"+newElm+"</ul>");
    }
}
```

The list can be up to 15,000 list 'li' items. with about 6500 items, the data is retrieved from the server in approx. 1.5 seconds but takes about 4.4 seconds after that to build and paint the list. This is by far the quickest i've seen so far but 11k+ items is normal.  I also want to minimize any pluggins because this list is drag/droppable and pretty dynamic so drag/droppable doesn't become activated until hovering over the 'span'.

Any pointer are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to break it down. In the point that the user wont see 15k entries at once! First get the most important- render the client. then progress to the next.. until all is done. Or you will need to use server side rendering instead with something like linq, xml transformations etc..

Comment: you may want to break it down to small parts like load the 1st 500 then with ajax code get another 500 from the server and so on, but 11k+ is soo much to handle through html and js (from my opinion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few links to guide you in jquery performance and appending items to the dom

- [reasons-to-use-append-correctly](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly)
- [5 easy tips on how to improve your code performance while working with huge data sets in jQuery](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/5-easy-tips-on-how-to-improve-code.html)